# Blazor: Not triggering @if check when variable is changed in the code

Tags: c#, html, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a `.razor` page in my **Blazor.Server** program called `EditPerson.razor`.

This page is opened when the user does a double click on a table row in another page.

The page initialize doing a GET request to the API that return that person's data based on the `id` passed in the **URL parameter**.

In the `html/razor` part I have two components that are the main form for the person's personal data and a tab area for addresses and contact info.

Then I have tow `@if`checks that control the show of two modals dialog, one for errors and other for the success message.

The problem is that when I change the *boolean* variable to show the success message, the `@if` checks are not triggered and the modal is never show.

**This is the `html/razor` code for example:**

```html
@page "/pessoas/edit/{PessoaId}"

@inject IPessoaApiService _apiService
@inject NavigationManager _uriHelper;

@using Ekklesia.Web.Library.Models.Pessoa
@using Ekklesia.Web.Library.Models.UI.Modais
@using Core.Enums
@using Ekklesia.Web.Library.Interfaces

<PageTitle>Ekklesia - Editar Pessoa</PageTitle>

<div id="pessoa-insert" class="container-fluid p-2">

    <div class="card ekklesia-form">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h1 class="display-4 ps-2 pt-1">Editar Pessoa</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <PessoaDadosForm Pessoa="Pessoa" @ref="PessoaDadosForm" />
            <GradePessoa Pessoa="Pessoa" />
            
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse m-2 me-2">
                <div class="ms-3">
                  <SfButton CssClass="e-primary"
                        @onclick="Update">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-check me-2"></i>Salvar
                  </SfButton></div>
                <div>
                  <SfButton CssClass="e-secundary"
                        @onclick="Voltar">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-ban me-2"></i>Voltar
                  </SfButton></div>
            </div>
        </div>          
    </div>
    
    @if (_showErrorModal)
    {
        <ModalBase Modal="@_erroModal"
            OnFecharModal="@OnFecharModalErro"/>
    }
    
    @if (_showSuccessModal)
    {
        <ModalBase Modal="@_successModal"
            OnFecharModal="@OnFecharModalSucesso"/>
    }
```

**And here is the `@code` part:**

```cs
@code {

    #region Parâmetros e campos internos

    [Parameter]
    public string PessoaId { get; set; }

    private PessoaDadosForm? PessoaDadosForm { get; set; }

    private PessoaViewModel _pessoa = new();

    private PessoaViewModel Pessoa
    {
        get { return _pessoa ?? new(); }
        set { _pessoa = value; }
    }

    private bool _showErrorModal = false;
    private ModalBaseViewModel _erroModal = new();
    
    private bool _showSuccessModal = false;
    private ModalBaseViewModel _successModal = new();

    #endregion

    #region Overrides

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var response = await _apiService.Get(pessoaId: Convert.ToInt32(PessoaId));

        if (response.Success 
            && response.StatusCode is HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            if (response.Data is not null)
            {
                var pessoa = response.Data.SingleOrDefault();
                Pessoa = pessoa ?? throw new Exception($"A busca pela pessoa de ID {PessoaId} retornou nula");
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Métodos da page

    private async Task Update()
    {
        Pessoa.Sexo = (SexoEnum)PessoaDadosForm.SexoInt;
        Pessoa.Tipo = (TipoPessoaEnum)PessoaDadosForm.TipoInt;
        Pessoa.Status = StatusEnum.Ativo;

        var response = await _apiService.Update(Pessoa, Convert.ToInt32(PessoaId));

        if (response.StatusCode is HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var resultado = response.Data ?? Pessoa;
            _pessoa = new();
            
            AbrirModalSucesso("A atualização foi um sucesso.", response.Message);
        }
        else
        {
            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> erros = new();

            response.Errors.ForEach(e =>
            {
                erros.Add(
                    new(e.Field == "DataNascimento" ? "Data Nascimento" : e.Field, e.Message));
            });

            AbrirModalErro("A inserção da nova pessoa falhou.", response.Message, erros);
        }
    }

    private void Voltar()
    {
        _pessoa = new();
        _uriHelper.NavigateTo("/pessoas");
    }

    #endregion

    #region Modais

    private void OnFecharModalErro()
    {
        InicializarModalErro();

        _erroModal.ModalClass = "fade";
        _erroModal.ModalDisplay = "hidden";
        _erroModal.ShowBackdrop = false;

        _showErrorModal = false;
    }
    
    private void OnFecharModalSucesso()
    {
        InicializarModalSucesso();

        _successModal.ModalClass = "fade";
        _successModal.ModalDisplay = "hidden";
        _successModal.ShowBackdrop = false;

        _showSuccessModal = false;
        
        _uriHelper.NavigateTo("pessoas");
    }

    private void AbrirModalErro(string texto, string descricao, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> erros)
    {
        InicializarModalErro();

        _erroModal.Texto = texto;
        _erroModal.Descricao = descricao;
        _erroModal.Erros = erros;

        _erroModal.ModalClass = "show";
        _erroModal.ModalDisplay = "block";
        _erroModal.ShowBackdrop = true;
        
        _showErrorModal = true;
    }
    
    private void AbrirModalSucesso(string texto, string descricao)
    {
        InicializarModalSucesso();

        _successModal.Texto = texto;
        _successModal.Descricao = descricao;

        _successModal.ModalClass = "show";
        _successModal.ModalDisplay = "block";
        _successModal.ShowBackdrop = true;
        
        _showSuccessModal = true;
    }

    private void InicializarModalErro()
    {
        _erroModal = new() 
        {
            Titulo = "Ocoreu um erro", 
            ModalTipo = "modal-erro", 
            ModalBotaoPrincipalTexto = "Entendi"
        };
    }
    
    private void InicializarModalSucesso()
    {
        _successModal = new()
        {
            Titulo = "Sucesso", 
            ModalTipo = "modal-sucesso", 
            ModalBotaoPrincipalTexto = "Ok"
        };
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**The success message modal is to been opened in this portion:**

```cs
private void AbrirModalSucesso(string texto, string descricao)
    {
        InicializarModalSucesso();

        _successModal.Texto = texto;
        _successModal.Descricao = descricao;

        _successModal.ModalClass = "show";
        _successModal.ModalDisplay = "block";
        _successModal.ShowBackdrop = true;
        
        _showSuccessModal = true;
    }
```

**Here is where the modal data is prepared:**

```cs
private void InicializarModalSucesso()
    {
        _successModal = new()
        {
            Titulo = "Sucesso", 
            ModalTipo = "modal-sucesso", 
            ModalBotaoPrincipalTexto = "Ok"
        };
    }
```

**This is the modal code:**

```html
@using Ekklesia.Web.Library.Models.UI.Modais

<div class="modal @Modal.ModalClass" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" style="display:@Modal.ModalDisplay">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header ekklesia-modal-header @Modal.ModalTipo">
                <h5 class="modal-title">@Modal.Titulo</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="ekklesia-form">
                    <div class="d-sm-flex flex-row">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <div class="modal-texto">
                                @Modal.Texto
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-descricao">
                                @Modal.Descricao
                                @if (Modal.ModalTipo == "modal-erro")
                                {
                                    @if (Modal.Erros.Count > 0)
                                    {
                                        <div class="card p-1 mt-3">
                                            <div class="card-body p-1">
                                                @foreach (var erro in @Modal.Erros)
                                                {
                                                    <div>
                                                        <b>Campo:</b> @erro.Key <br/>
                                                        <b>Erro:</b> @erro.Value
                                                    </div>
                                                    <hr />
                                                }
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    }
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                    
            </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-@(Modal.ModalTipo == "modal-erro" ? "danger" : "success")" 
                    @onclick="Confirm">@Modal.ModalBotaoPrincipalTexto</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@if (Modal.ShowBackdrop)
{
    <div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>
}

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public ModalBaseViewModel Modal { get; set; } = new();
    
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback OnFecharModal { get; set; }

    private async Task Confirm()
    {
        await OnFecharModal.InvokeAsync();
    }

}
```

I have another page for creating new persons and in there I used the same aproach for the modals and worked there.

I have tried to invoke the `StateHasChanged()` method in different parts of the process but it changed noting.

I have tried for some 4 hours to resolve this before asking for help here.

Please, if anyone can help, I will be very gratefull!

P.S.: This is my very first question here, if more info is needed please comment bellow that I will be watching for tips.

*I am from Brazil, that's is why some parts of the code have portuguese words.*

*I am using some Syncfusion components in those code examples.*

**This is how the page looks rigth now:**
[Edit page print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAT5p.png)

Comment: This has quite a lot of code, and we can't run/debug it. Isolate your problems, can you show the Modals at all?   Create a testpage with 1 or 2 modals and a simplified Update(). You can add Task.Delay() to simulate the async HttpClient calls etc. See [mre].

Comment: Your naming convention of variables are horrible.  Some case you have "erro" and other cases "error". the some cases you have dashes in the names and other cases underscores.  My suspicions right now are the names are not matching.   I would put a break point on the following statement and check if error has an 'r' at the end :  @if (Modal.ModalTipo == "modal-erro")

Comment: Hi.  Henk is right, but I can just about follow the code.  What I can't see at the moment is what calls `Update`?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis There's an `SfButton` in the card footer with `@onclick="Update".`

Comment: Hi Henk and Shaun. Thanks for the tips.
I wrote a simpler page as by yours suggestions with only a button and the modal and i discovered the cause of the problem.

That page had no knowledge about the modal component, was necessary to insert a new @using for it's namespace. Was placed it in a folder called *Modals*. That's why it was not opening the modal.

The `Update` changed the value of the variable but because the page doesn't know the component it was never rendered.

Comment: No problem, I was about to ask you to add this to the `@if` statement -  `<div>Hello _showSuccessModal is true<div>` which would have highlighted the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to test your code right now, my first suggestion would be to try and call `StateHasChanged()` after updating `_showErrorModal`